# Keep a service running all the time even after a reboot

Tags: java, android, service

I have implelemented the    START_STICKY     command but the service is killed after a few hours. What I want to do is keep a service running always in the background and restart even when the device is rebooted. Can I restart the service in the onDestroy method like this? or is there a more convenient approach to it?

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {

   Stop();

    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    startService(i);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

For ensuring that your service is running even after some hours of starting it, then you will have to use `AlarmManager` which will run recurringly for a specified periodicity even if the app is killed. What will you do is register a `PendingIntent` for the `AlarmManager` to fire which will be received by a `BroadcastReceiver` and in the `BroadcastReceiver` you will check that if your Service is running or not. If running, do nothing and if not then start the service.

> **What I want to do is keep a service running always in the background and restart even when the device is rebooted.**

In order to do this you will have to give this permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and then you will have to make a custom `BroadcastReceiver` which will check for an intent to be fired which is `Action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

You should declare your BroadcastReceiver to catch the above mentioned intent in the Android Manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
  <intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
  </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Now either you can initialise your AlarmManager in `BroadcastReceiver` class or you can write the code to start the service straightaway.

Info on AlarmManager can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

> **Disclaimer:**
>   Starting from *Android O*, Google will stop supporting Unbound Background Service and calling startService() will become Illegal(Android will throw IllegalStateException) when calling this function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed information, I guess I'll have to use the Alarm Manager and do you know what will we be using after the official release of Android O?

Comment: After Android O, you will be left with two Options:
1. JobScheduler, introduced for Android API 21 and above and,
2. Firebase JobDispatcher API which is backward compatible upto API 9.